# Hibernate query to get server time without converting to local timezone

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I've searched high and low for an answer to this and I've found nothing. Note (before someone refers me to a similar, but unhelpful question) that I'm NOT STORING ANY DATES/TIMES IN THE DATABASE.

**Background**

I have a Postgres database that's running on a server somewhere. I have a Java back end that queries the database using Hibernate. The database server and the Java back end (Tomcat server) are running on separate systems, and can be in different timezones.

The server needs to perform some cleanup tasks at a specific time (which can be configured by the user) - for example, delete entries older than x days every day at noon. I'm trying to run a query on the server to get the current server time. The problem is that either hibernate or the JVM is converting the time from the time on the database server to the local time on the server running Tomcat.

**Example**

I have a database server (Postgres) on a server using Central Time (UTC-6). I have my back end server (Java/Tomcat) using GMT (UTC+0). I have a query that I can run to get the current time (SELECT now()). Let's say that the current time on the database server is 12:00:00. If I run the query from the back end server on the database server using pgAdmin, it returns the correct time (12:00:00). If I run the same query using Hibernate, it converts it to GMT (18:00:00).

**Question**

Is there a query that I can run from the back end server (Java/Tomcat) that will get the current time from the database server without converting it? Alternatively, is there something that I can do to the time that's returned so that I can convert it back to the time on the database server?

Comment: to me, this: *I'm trying to run a query on the server to get the current server time* is the wrong part. It seems that your dates are not saved as `UTC`.

Comment: The dates that I'm saving in the database are all stored as UTC timestamps. That's not the issue. The problem is that I want to do something at (for example) midnight on the database server, but the action is kicked off by the Tomcat server (there's a Java scheduled task that runs at the top of each hour, checks the time on the database server and starts doing something). I'm unable to get the database time though, as it always gets processed as local (Tomcat server) time. I have no idea what time it is on the database server.

Comment: Example: "SELECT NOW()" always returns local (Tomcat) server time, not the database server time.

Comment: Did you try using the Postgres `to_char` function and retrieving the result as a `String` instead of a `Timestamp`?

Comment: Yes, I did. It appears to return the timezone and then convert to char locally, because I still get the same (incorrect) value. Frustratingly, everything that I've tried works via pgAdmin. It seems to be a Hibernate and/or JVM issue.

Comment: honestly I did not know about this, but seems the problem being here http://blog.montrosesoftware.com/2016/11/08/dates-and-times-in-java-unexpected-timezone-shift/

Comment: @Eugene - Thanks. That's helpful. Not sure if it's an actual solution but there are things that I can look into.

Answer (score 0):

Time on Tomcat server is 18:00 then below sql would return 12:00...

```
select current_timestamp - (interval '6' hour)
```

Comment: ...but how do I get the interval? I don't know what timezones the servers are running in beforehand, and if I run a query to get the interval (e.g. select extract(timezone from now())/3600.0) then it converts that to local time as well (i.e. for GMT it returns 0 even though I run it on the database server using CST time which should return -6). I can't just hardwire an interval into the code - it needs to run dynamically.

Comment: `current_timestamp` is a `timestamp WITH time zone` so it is converted to the client's timezone anyway

Comment: Yes - but it's the "(interval '6' hour)" that I'm asking about. I can see that the query gets the timestamp and then adjusts it back to server time by taking 6 hours off it (GMT -> CST). However, I don't know which timezones my servers are running in ahead of time, so I can't hardwire a value of '6' into there for the adjustment. I need to get this dynamically, but when I do that it adjusts the timezone offset as well.